# How to navigate to already opened page in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.forms.shell

Every time I open a page from menu same instance is opened. But when I navigate to the same page from some other page (Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//MyOrdersPage")) a new instance is opened.
How to navigate to already opened page's instance in xamarin?

Comment: I tested with the default xamarin.forms shell application template. When I use the Shell.Current.GoToAsync() in the page, it will also go to the existed instance instead of create a new one.

Comment: Thanks , You are right . It was some incorrect condition which was giving incorrect impression.